# how to integrate module developed in separate winform application?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, module

i need to integrate modules that are developed in separate win form application.Application can run and test individual and in the integrated.i required to create a set up and deploy at client site.My two biggest challenges are keep assemblies in one place and reference them in application.

For Example

Module 1. A stand alone application for user management 
Module 2. A stand alone application for Role and Assignment management

now i have to create a application that can show forms and mdi form from these two application.

Comment: @Vivek: I vaguely understand what you are asking, but not well enough to give a good answer.  Consider improving your question, perhaps by getting a bit more concrete.

Comment: I think he's talking about having several projects and one of them is shared between all the others?

Comment: @Eric j 
i want to create a application that can open different applications that are developed stand alone.

Comment: You mean open them as in load them dynamically at runtime, or load them as in link to them?

Comment: @Eric j , i want to load them dynamically and open  by using reflection.I want to open their start up  mdi form.

Answer (score 0):

So you're basically looking for a plugin-architecture?

If so, here's a good tutorial about that: http://www.divelements.com/net/articles/plugins/plugins.asp.

Actually, there is already a framework, from Microsoft, available. It's called MEF (Managed Extensibility Framework) and can be found [here at Codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com/MEF).